# How can I reed this text data using pandas, each category in a separate column?

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, statistics

I need to put auth_name, univ, department on columns of df from the following text data:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOIzN.png)

Comment: you could have explained better the problem

Comment: It is a column that contains the names of the scientific publishing and the participating departments, and I try to extract all the department from the column to find out the most participating departments in publishing  but ts too hard to me to get the departments  by search on colunm

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd

data =  '[Bashiri, Fahad A.; Hamad, Muddathir H.; Kentab, Amal Y.; Salih, Mustafa A.; Al Nasser, Mohammad N.] King Saud Univ, King Khalid Univ Hosp, King Saud Univ Med City, Div Neurol, Riyadh, Saudi Arabia; [Hamad, Muddathir H.; Amer, Yasser S.; Abouelkheir, Manal M.; Mohamed, Sarar; Al-Ahmadi, Tahani; Iqbal, Shaikh M.] King Saud Univ, King Khalid Univ Hosp, King Saud Univ Med City, Pediat CPGs Dept Comm, Riyadh, Saudi Arabia; [Al-Eyadhy, Ayman A.] King Saud Univ, King Khalid Univ Hosp, King Saud Univ Med City, Pediat Intens Care Unit, Riyadh, Saudi Arabia; [Al-Ahmadi, Tahani] King Saud Univ, King Khalid Univ Hosp, King Saud Univ Med City, Div Gen Pediat, Riyadh, Saudi Arabia; [Alnemri, Abdulrahman M.] King Saud Univ, King Khalid Univ Hosp, King Saud Univ Med City, Div Neonatol,Dept Pediat, Riyadh, Saudi Arabia; [Al Othman, Mohammed A.] King Saud Univ, King Khalid Univ Hosp, King Saud Univ Med City, Pediat Emergency Unit,Emergency Med Dept, Riyadh, Saudi Arabia; [Somily, Ali M.] King Saud Univ, King Khalid Univ Hosp, King Saud Univ Med City, Dept Pathol & Lab Med,Microbiol Unit, Riyadh, Saudi Arabia; [Al-Ansary, Lubna A.] King Saud Univ, King Khalid Univ Hosp, King Saud Univ Med City, Dept Family Community Med,Coll Med, Riyadh, Saudi Arabia; [Amer, Yasser S.] King Saud Univ, King Khalid Univ Hosp, King Saud Univ Med City, Qual Management Dept, Riyadh, Saudi Arabia; [Amer, Yasser S.; Abouelkheir, Manal M.; Iqbal, Shaikh M.; Wahabi, Hayfaa A.; Al-Ansary, Lubna A.] King Saud Univ, King Khalid Univ Hosp, King Saud Univ Med City, Clin Practice Guidelines Steering Comm, Riyadh, Saudi Arabia; [Amer, Yasser S.; Wahabi, Hayfaa A.; Al-Ansary, Lubna A.] King Saud Univ, King Khalid Univ Hosp, King Saud Univ Med City, Res Chair Evidence Based Hlth Care & Knowledge Tr, Riyadh, Saudi Arabia; [Abouelkheir, Manal M.] King Saud Univ, King Khalid Univ Hosp, King Saud Univ Med City, Pediat Clin Pharm Serv, Riyadh, Saudi Arabia; [Bashiri, Fahad A.; Kentab, Amal Y.; Salih, Mustafa A.; Hundallah, Khalid J.; Alwadei, Ali H.; Albaradie, Raidah S.; Al-Twaijri, Waleed A.; Jan, Mohammed M.] Prince Sultan Mil Med City, Dept Pediat, Saudi Pediat Neurol Soc, Riyadh, Saudi Arabia; [Mohamed, Sarar] Prince Sultan Mil Med City, Dept Pediat, Genet Metab Div, Riyadh, Saudi Arabia; [Hundallah, Khalid J.] Prince Sultan Mil Med City, Dept Pediat, Pediat Neurol, Riyadh, Saudi Arabia; [Wahabi, Hayfaa A.] King Fahad Med City, Natl Neurosci Inst, Pediat Neurol Dept, Riyadh, Saudi Arabia; [Al-Twaijri, Waleed A.] Natl Guard King Saud bin Abdulaziz Univ, King Abdullah Specialist Children Hosp, Riyadh, Saudi Arabia; [Al-Otaibi, Faisal] King Faisal Specialist Hosp & Res Ctr, Dept Neurosci, Riyadh, Saudi Arabia; [Al-Otaibi, Faisal] Saudi Epilepsy Soc, Gulf League Epilepsy, Riyadh, Saudi Arabia; [Albaradie, Raidah S.; Jan, Mohammed M.; Alnemri, Abdulrahman M.] Saudi Epilepsy Soc, Riyadh, Saudi Arabia; [Albaradie, Raidah S.] King Fahad Specialist Hosp, Dept Pediat Neurol, Dammam, Saudi Arabia; [Jan, Mohammed M.] King Abdulaziz Univ, Fac Med, Dept Pediat, Jeddah, Saudi Arabia; [Iqbal, Shaikh M.] Univ Manitoba, Dept Pediat & Child Hlth, Sect Respirol, Winnipeg, MB, Canada; [Bashiri, Fahad A.] King Saud Univ, King Khalid Univ Hosp, Coll Med, Dept Pediat, Riyadh, Saudi Arabia'
data_list = [[i.split('] ')[0], i.split('] ')[1].split(', ', 1)[0], i.split('] ')[1].split(', ', 1)[1]] for i in data[1:].split('; [')]
df = pd.DataFrame(data_list, columns=['auth_name','univ','department'])
```

output `df.head()`:

|  | auth_name | univ | department |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Bashiri, Fahad A.; Hamad, Muddathir H.; Kentab, Amal Y.; Salih, Mustafa A.; Al Nasser, Mohammad N. | King Saud Univ | King Khalid Univ Hosp, King Saud Univ Med City, Div Neurol, Riyadh, Saudi Arabia |
| 1 | Hamad, Muddathir H.; Amer, Yasser S.; Abouelkheir, Manal M.; Mohamed, Sarar; Al-Ahmadi, Tahani; Iqbal, Shaikh M. | King Saud Univ | King Khalid Univ Hosp, King Saud Univ Med City, Pediat CPGs Dept Comm, Riyadh, Saudi Arabia |
| 2 | Al-Eyadhy, Ayman A. | King Saud Univ | King Khalid Univ Hosp, King Saud Univ Med City, Pediat Intens Care Unit, Riyadh, Saudi Arabia |
| 3 | Al-Ahmadi, Tahani | King Saud Univ | King Khalid Univ Hosp, King Saud Univ Med City, Div Gen Pediat, Riyadh, Saudi Arabia |
| 4 | Alnemri, Abdulrahman M. | King Saud Univ | King Khalid Univ Hosp, King Saud Univ Med City, Div Neonatol,Dept Pediat, Riyadh, Saudi Arabia |

To split the authors in `auth_name` [to different rows](https://programmer.ink/think/pandas-how-do-i-split-text-in-a-column-into-multiple-lines-python.html):

```
df = df['auth_name'].str.split('; ', expand=True).stack().reset_index(level=0).set_index('level_0').rename(columns={0:'auth_name'}).join(df.drop('auth_name', axis=1))
```

output `df.head()`:

|  | auth_name | univ | department |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Bashiri, Fahad A. | King Saud Univ | King Khalid Univ Hosp, King Saud Univ Med City, Div Neurol, Riyadh, Saudi Arabia |
| 0 | Hamad, Muddathir H. | King Saud Univ | King Khalid Univ Hosp, King Saud Univ Med City, Div Neurol, Riyadh, Saudi Arabia |
| 0 | Kentab, Amal Y. | King Saud Univ | King Khalid Univ Hosp, King Saud Univ Med City, Div Neurol, Riyadh, Saudi Arabia |
| 0 | Salih, Mustafa A. | King Saud Univ | King Khalid Univ Hosp, King Saud Univ Med City, Div Neurol, Riyadh, Saudi Arabia |
| 0 | Al Nasser, Mohammad N. | King Saud Univ | King Khalid Univ Hosp, King Saud Univ Med City, Div Neurol, Riyadh, Saudi Arabia |

Comment: if data in  df['col']   how  this code be iam try but it it git error as                                            AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: My code assumes that the input data is a text string. Are you saying you are getting it from a dataframe? Then how is the dataframe structured? What are you trying to parse?

Comment: It is a column that contains the names of the scientific publishing and the participating departments, and I try to extract all the department from the column to find out the most participating departments in publishing

Comment: Assuming all publications are in a different cell in the column `df['col']`, you can try this: `df[['auth_name', 'univ', 'department']] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series([[i.split('] ')[0], i.split('] ')[1].split(', ', 1)[0], i.split('] ')[1].split(', ', 1)[1]] for i in x[1:].split('; [')][0]))`

Comment: "TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable"  it gives this error

Comment: So again the question: how is your data structured? Please put the output of `df.head()` in the original question. I cannot help you as long as I don't know what the input data looks like.

Comment: df['KSU 1'][0]   

'[Bashiri, Fahad A.; Hamad, Muddathir H.; Kentab, Amal Y.; Salih, Mustafa A.; Al Nasser, Mohammad N.] King Saud Univ, King Khalid Univ Hosp, King Saud Univ Med City, Div Neurol, Riyadh, Saudi Arabia'  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOIzN.png

Comment: Try this. First `df = df.stack().reset_index()`, then `df = df[df[0] != "-"]`, then `df[['auth_name', 'univ', 'department']] = df[0].apply(lambda x: pd.Series([[i.split('] ')[0], i.split('] ')[1].split(', ', 1)[0], i.split('] ')[1].split(', ', 1)[1]] for i in x[1:].split('; [')][0]))`

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_depart(df,col):
    x = []
    for i in range(len(df)):
        y= re.findall(r'(?i)((?:\w+\s)?{0}(?:\s\w+)?)'.format('Dept'), df[col][i])
        #print(y,len(y))
        x.append(y)
    return(x)
out counts 
[Dept Chem]                                     4300 
[Dept Bot]                                      2459 
[Dept Zool]                                     2206 
[Dept Pharmaceut]                               2058 
[Dept Phys]                                     1616 
[Dept Math]                                     1431 
[DeptBiochem]                                   690 
[Dept Food]                                     687 
[Dept Pharmacognosy]                            670
```